# Swing - "Hint" text Util making text blurry?

Tags: java, swing

So I have this Util class that gives "Hint" text in a text area. Also know as gray text, like "Search" in gray and then your search phrase is in normal text. I have a similiar setup. This is what it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK8dE.png]

If you can tell, the text seems blurry, or grainy. I have no idea what's causing the problem. Here is what it looks like when text is entered in the field:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj7ud.png]

As you can tell, the text is not grainy like the previous one. This is the same text area. This is how it's used in my class:

```
username.setUI(new TemplateText("Username", false, Color.GRAY));
```

Here is the Util class: http://pastebin.com/wuzxeXPs

Comment: Since I require 10 Rep to add a third link, here is the picture with the Field filled with text: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hj7ud.png

Comment: `Since I require 10 Rep to add a third link,` - don't post a link to your code. Code should be posted in the forum so we can all see it. Also, it should be in the form or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Check out [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for another class that has this functionality. Maybe you will have better luck with the painting.

Comment: The only Text Prompts I am aware of are the JTextArea and JTextField. Do you know of any others? I am somewhat new to Swing.

Comment: What? I just gave you a link (well I gave it to you a week ago. Its nice of you to respond so fast) to different code that implements the text prompt differently. I don't notice the painting problem.

Comment: Is this (http://www.camick.com/java/source/TextPrompt.java) the link you mean? If so, let me try it out! I hope it works! As for the very late reply, sorry for that, I've been busy with school, and on top of that this is a side project. Thanks!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!